# How to use MySQL view in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, view

I would like to use a view that I've created in MySQL as model in Django.  I would like to show the status of unfinished processes going on at my company on my intranet site. I have found only rather old entries on forums, so is there an easy way to pass MySQL view through `syncdb`?

If not, assume I have a two tables:

1. hard-writen milestones of subprocesses, e.g :
2. table with processess and subprocesses info as ID from table above :
   [image]
3. My view in MySQL would do something like that.
   4) So the outcome would be :

[image]

I would like to have only one model in my django APP, the outcome no.4.
What is the quickest way to get this ? Custom SQL query? Or do I need to have models for `progress_tb` and `proc_tb` and combine them? How do I refer to the same table few times (as in Access/MySQL I have `progress_tb` as `progress_tb_1` et c.) ? And by now I know only how to make a filtered query, but how can I "add" few columns from joined table ? I tried "extra" option from django, but I don't understand how it works :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify your view as *not* being managed by Django through a `managed = False` field declaration on your nested `Meta` class:

```
class MyViewModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    [...]

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'MyView' # your view name
```

`managed = False` will cause `python manage.py syncdb` to ignore that model for sync'ing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give a try tomorrow ! will it work even though the view wasn't recognized by syncdb ? I just have to name the fields exactly as they are in my view ?

Comment: Yes. It will still work without `syncdb` manipulating it.  That's what the `managed` field was designed to do.  You don't _have_ to name the fields exactly as in your view, but if the fields have good, comprehensible names, then you maybe you should.  If you want to separate the view's field names from your Django model's field names, you can specify the [`db_column` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-column) to your fields' model instantiation.  e.g. `field1 = models.IntegerField(db_column='super_crappy_field_name')`

Comment: so how my MyViewModel will know that "field1" is actually "sub_Proc1_%" and "field2" is "sub_Proc2_%" (from given example ) ? cause i did catch that one.

Comment: Ok, `sub_Proc1` _can_ be renamed, but it doesn't have to be.  If you don't want to rename it, just do `sub_Proc1 = models.IntegerField()` ( or whatever the correct model type is).  If you _do_ want to rename it, use field `db_column` - `sub_Proc1_renamed  = models.IntegerField(db_column='sub_Proc1')`.  [See `db_column` documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-column)

Comment: On more thought, Jakub.  Multiple tables with just a prefix name change is gonna bite ya.  You could combine those tables with a `union` in your view.   `select prefix, foo, bar from (select 1 as prefix, foo, bar from sub_Proc1_1) s_1 union (select 2 as prefix, foo, bar from sub_Proc1_2) s_2 [...]`